# Why is SNI not working on IE 9 for Vista?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, sni

Based on well-known documentation, TLS SNI works on Windows Vista clients and later which use IE 7 and later. I've tried TLS SNI on Vista with IE 9, and it does work as expected.

However, a client is reporting that they can not connect to our web site via TLS SNI on a Vista IE9 client. He can connect using non-SNI TLS, and he can also connect from the same LAN using an iPad to TLS SNI. So it seems that there is something on his computer which is blocking SNI. He checked Internet Options, and all SSL/TLS options are checked.

What could be the culprit preventing SNI from working? Is it a firewall and/or anti-virus software program? What are the known ones which typically break SNI?